# NTP Server in powershell : getting two different results

Tags: powershell, ntp

I have found two different powershell ways to get the FQDN and IP of the NTP server which my desktop is using but they give different results :

First way :

```
> (Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\W32Time\Parameters -Name NtpServer).split(',')[0]
time.windows.com
> (nslookup time.windows.com 2>$null | sls Address)[-1].ToString().Split()[-1]
51.145.123.29
```

Second way :

```
> (w32tm -query -status | sls ^Source).ToString().Split()[1]
ntpServer.myLAN.lan
> (nslookup ntpServer.myLAN.lan 2>$null | sls Address)[-1].ToString().Split()[-1]
X.Y.Z.T
> (w32tm -query -status | sls ^ID.*IP).ToString().Split()[-1].Split(')')[0]
X.Y.Z.T
```

Which is the "right" one ?

Comment: Look at the `Source: ` line output by `w32tm` instead - will give you the NTP Servers host name instead of the IP

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen The `Source:` line returns a different FQDN than `time.windows.com`.